# error says it a Pandas DataFrame when dumping a Python dict

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary, but when I try to dump it as a *JSON* file, it says it is a Pandas DataFrame!

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
import json

files_net = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if re.match(r'network_.+.json', f)]
    
networks = {}
for file in files_net:
    with open(file) as f:
        networks[re.search(r'network_(.+).json', file).group(1)] = pd.read_json(f)
type(networks)

>>> dict

with open('networks.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(networks, f)

TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `networks` is a dictionary, but values of it are `pd.DataFrame`s because they come from `pd.read_json`; hence the error. You might try `to_json` whilst forming the key-value pairs:

```
networks[re.search(r'network_(.+).json', file).group(1)] = pd.read_json(f).to_json()
```

But since you are `read`ing `json` anyway, you might use `json` module in the first place e.g. `json.load(f)`.